# Microsoft graph Api get sharepoint list items, found no item using query $filter=indexOf or $search

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get list items from SharePoint list by **searching the title of the item** with specific keywords.
But I got stuck in using Graph API query parameter $filter or $search.

### I Have been Succeeded in Getting the List Items

- Here is the URL I use and the query without using $filter

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items?
$select=id
&$expand=fields($select=id,title)
```

- [I succeed  getting the response as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mSVW.png)

```
       [{
            "fields": {
                "id": "1",
                "Title": "由工作触发的私聊和群聊"
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "id": "2",
                "Title": "在地图中分析 Excel 大数据"
            }
        }]
```

- When I add the $filter=startsWith(fields, '在地图'), [it still work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkF4c.png)

```
// URL
items?
$select=id
&$expand=fields($select=id,title)
&$filter=startsWith(fields/Title, '在地图')

// Response
   [{
      "fields": {
         "@odata.etag": "\"d72d8ed2-967f-4fd2-b198-b668477cca03,1\"",
         "id": "2",
         "Title": "在地图中分析 Excel 大数据"
      }
   }]
```

### Then I Got Stuck

- Once I try to use $filter=indexOf(fields/Title, '在地图') eq 0, [I receive error: no item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQmMZ.png)

```
// URL
items?
$select=id
&$expand=fields($select=id,title)
&$filter=indexOf(fields/Title, '在地图') eq 0

// Response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-23T07:12:48",
            "request-id": "a2c73b82-cac4-44b4-ae8c-3f7073ecd4f9",
            "client-request-id": "6ba8a042-62b3-d067-b66f-d05258abb880"
        }
    }
}
```

- Then I tried to use $search instead, but just receive the whole list items, [it didn't work too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKu3i.png)

### Does anyone figure out Any Way to Resolve the Problem?

any way to search the items' title using  graph api would be help!

---

update

I found the solution, search API could help, but got new problem.
I post the body with lots of fields item as below.

```
// request body
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "Teams"
            },
            "fields": [
                "id",
                "VideoUrl",
                "ImgUrl",
                "Post",
                "Category",
                "SaveTime",
                "title",
                "created",
                "Modified",
                "author",
                "Editor",
                "ContentType"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but only got little fields of the items as below

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)",
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [
                "teams"
            ],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "total": 15,
                    "moreResultsAvailable": false,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "hitId": "0B94FBE2-0A2B-46EA-8AA0-B37670E4252A",
                            "rank": 1,
                            "summary": "在日常工作中...",
                            "resource": {
                                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.listItem",
                                "id": "0B94FBE2-0A2B-46EA-8AA0-B37670E4252A",
                                "fields": {
                                    "title": "利用 Teams 快速发起文档协作",
                                    "created": "2020-09-18T09:21:42Z",
                                    "author": "sangyak",
                                    "contentType": "项目"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                 }
               ]
             }
           ]
       }
```

why only  "title", "created", "author", "ContentType" included?

Comment: Can you include the response instead of linking to images?

Comment: I think I did include the response in code below the link, or is there some more should I include?

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the fields you want in your query? I'm not sure why, but I also get a small subset of the fields when I query a list. I have to add the expand onto the end to get the rest of the data like:

`&$select=id&$expand=fields($select=mycustomfield1,mycustomfield2,mycustomfield3,etc)`

I can also simply put a wildcard in like below to see all the fields:

`&$select=id&$expand=fields($select=*)`

For these types of queries, I normally do not want all of the extra data on the main record, so I include that `select=id` to because I only want the id field.